# Retain specific characters in a column using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created the following table using SQL:

```
   create table TableName(col1 string1(character varying(5000), col2 int);
```

Now I want to retain all the characters in string1 like: ",',a-z,A-Z,numbers,/. I want to delete the rest of the characters in string1.  I am working on postgressql 9.1.

Is there some way by which I may achieve this?

```
Sample Data:  "http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20726193/edit\0 ~@#$$%%^ abc def"
Result: "http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20726193/edit abc def"
```

Comment: Your title is "Delete specific rows" your question is about characters?  Please give sample data and desired results to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for pointing this out. Very sorry for the typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`regexp_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) is probably your best bet in situations like this, something like:

```
regexp_replace(col1, E'[^a-z0-9:/\\s]', 'gi')
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/031c1/3

Adjust the character class to suit your exact needs.

Comment: Can you also please explain it a bit

Comment: Are you familiar with [regexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)?

Comment: I am not getting what does \s and 'gi' mean here

Comment: The `\s` means "whitespace": spaces, tabs, CRs, LFs, vertical tabs. The `'gi'` argument are the flags: `g` for "global replace" rather than just the first match, `i` for case insensitive. The `E''` notation means that C-style `\n` and such work in the string so `\\s` is needed to get a plain `\s` into the regex engine.